# Setting BASE_DIR and PROJECT_DIR appropriately for my Django project to capture my STATICFILES_DIRS

Tags: django, python-2.7

Below is my project structure in Django 1.11.

```
repo-directory/
├── addons
|   |__ project1
|       |__ static
|       |__ template
|       |__ model.py
|   |__ project2
|       |__ static
|       |__ template
|       |__ model.py
├── config
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── urls.py
|   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

What am trying to do is to set STATICFILES_DIRS to know where my static folder is. **So I did the following below** inside my `settings.py` file but did not resolve to be working properly.

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static/fonts/"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static/extras/"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static/img/"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static/js/"),
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**WSGI config**

```
"""
WSGI config for config project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Are you using Django's runserver or another server?  Please post your wsgi.py file.

Comment: @DanSwain Posted. Am using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: How does the error traceback look like?

Comment: @slackmart application runs, but static file just can't be located yet. I mean PROJECT_DIR is not in the root of the application but inside `addons` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to list the directories that are within the `static` directories.  Try this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "addons/project1/static"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "addons/project2/static"),
]
```

But, if you have `addons.project1` and `addons.project2` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you could just do the following without having to list anything in `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    ...,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    ...,
]
```

**UPDATE:**

However, I would suggest changing your `PROJECT_DIR` and `BASE_DIR` as follows:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)
```

and then updating your `STATICFILES_DIRS` as follows if you're going to use `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "addons/project1/static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "addons/project2/static"),
]
```

Comment: What about the `PROJECT_DIR` in your code, does that actually link to the right directory as I did explain how my structure is

Comment: I listed the first version of my answer around your definition of PROJECT_DIR, but see my update.  I think that defining PROJECT_DIR and BASE_DIR in the way I show in the update is more straightforward because you can then declare your static and media root folders as STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') and MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').  Done for tonight here.